# regex for a real number in flex ignoring leading zeros

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

I have the following sets:

```
NUMBER  [0-9]+
DECIMAL ("."{NUMBER})|({NUMBER}("."{NUMBER}?)?)
REAL    {DECIMAL}([eE][+-]?{NUMBER})?
```

and I want my lexer to accept real numbers like:
0.002 or 0.004e-10 or .01

the problem is that I want it ignore the leading zeros but to keep the rest of the number for example:

when I give 000.0002 I want to keep 0.0002 and when I give 0.2e-0100 I want to keep 0.2e-100

So I was thinking something like the atof function but I do not know how to do it exactly.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lex` will return the complete token that your pattern matches as one string.  You cannot change *that*.  At the expense of considerable complexity you could use start conditions to match a leading zero (which may be the only digit), and collect tokens for the pieces, e.g.,

```
0.2e-0100
```

as

```
0.2e-
0
100
```

and glue the first/last tokens together but you would find it *much* simpler to develop your own string function which filters out the unwanted leading zeroes.